# How slow is a call to a local database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, database

In general, say you have a (<16mb) table in a database running on the same machine as your server. If you need to do lots of querying into this table (%100 reads), is it better to:

1. Get the entire table, and do all the searching/querying/ in the server code.
2. Make lots of queries into the local database.

If the database is local, can I take advantage of the dbms's highly-efficient internal data structures for querying, or is the delay such that it's faster to map the tables returned by the database into my own data structures.

Thanks.

Comment: We have no crystal ball. You need to profile your own application. Many factors could be at play. It will depend on how you organize an in-memory copy anyways

Comment: There's no definitive answer since it depends on the nature of the queries and the size and structure of the data. You'd have to run a comparitive test, but I'd bet on the database running queries faster than you can.

Comment: @sehe OK that's actually very informative. All I needed to know was that the local calls were low enough that a profiling/comparative test was needed, and not obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to depend heavily on what kind of searches you're doing.

- If your data is all ID lookups, it's probably faster to have it in RAM.
- If your data is all full scans (no indexes), it's probably faster to have it in RAM.
- If your data uses indexes, it's probably faster to have it in the DB.

Of course, much of the appeal of a database is indexes and a common query interface, so you have to weigh how valuable those are versus raw speed.

There's no way to really answer this without knowing exactly the nature of the data and queries to be done on it. Over-the-wire time has its cost, as does BSON <-> native marshalling, but indexed searches can be O(log n) as opposed to a dumb O(n) (or worse) search over a simple in-memory data structure.

Have you tried benchmarking?

Comment: Not yet. I just needed to know what order of which it costs to make a local db query. From what I've now been told, it seems low enough that a profiling/analysis is necessary

Comment: Currently, I'm doing it all in RAM; but I found myself implementing a lot of things that DB's do internally anyways (only likely better). My natural thought was, can the DB do it so much faster that it makes it worthwhile taking the port call